# process does not terminate after killing shell script

Tags: shell

I have a shell script that executes two commands in parallel with out opening a new terminal

my script

```js
#!/bin/sh

sudo command1 &
sudo command2
```

I need a shell script that should terminate when i press cntl + c in terminal that executing the shell script

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to execute on exit using `trap`. Register the process ID of the forked process, and kill that PID in the exit function.

```
FORKED_PID=

# this function will be executed when the script is terminated for any reason
function finish() {
    # get the process id of the process with parent process id $FORKED_PID, and kill it
    sudo kill -9 `ps --ppid $FORKED_PID -o pid=`
}
# bind this function to the EXIT signal
trap finish EXIT

# run command1 with sudo
sudo command1 &
# get the process id from the previous command and put it in $FORKED_PID
FORKED_PID=$!
# run command2 with sudo
sudo command2
```

Comment: Not able to understand the solution, so blindly tried the code but it is not working

Comment: Forgot the effect sudo has on the whole thing, I adjusted my answer accordingly. I also added comments to hopefully make it more understandable.